# Why does length(x - 1) not equal length(x) - 1 in R?

Tags: r

If I define a vector `x` such that

`x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)`

Then `length(x)` gives 5.

But `length(x - 1)` gives 5 as well. The same goes for any other integer/real number I tried.

The correct code is thus `length(x) - *some integer*`.

I suspect this has something to do with vectors, but if somebody could offer a technical explanation I would be thankful.

Comment: Try `x-1` and ponder a wee bit.

Comment: That just removes the first element. So length(x[-2]) would return the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x - 1` equals `c(0,1,2,3,4)` i.e. applying a substraction by `1` for each element of the vector x, so the length stays the same. However, `length(x) - 1` applies the substraction after `length(x)` is computed.

```
> x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> x-1
[1] 0 1 2 3 4
> length(x-1)
[1] 5
```